# Ubuntu 14.04 game problems

Tags: games, playonlinux

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 14.04, and League of Legends and World of Warcraft have both stopped working.

With World of Warcraft, there are no error codes provided, and it just doesn't allow me to open the applications.

With League of Legends, the game client opens and allows me to log in, but once I'm in game, the shop you use to buy items freezes as soon as I click to open it.

---

I also found another problem.  I closed my League of Legends game over an hour ago that was being played on PlayOnLinux.  I then started to play Warthunder on STEAM, but that game froze in the queue finder, and League of Legends was there in the background, even though the game has been closed for over an hour.

I don't have any idea why it's doing that, and it could be many things maybe causing it.

Comment: You say they stopped working after you upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes everything stopped working once I upgraded to 14.04 everything was working perfectly fine on 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly "stopped working" means. Do the games not load? They load but have problems? Are there any error messages? How are you launching them? What do you mean _all_ your apps?

Comment: might be an infamous "upgrade break", sort of sideeffect if something went wrong during the upgrade. Sorry I can't help you with it, try to google it (or wait for someone wiser than me)

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll try google see If it will give me any fixes, Again thanks for your time and help :).

Comment: @Philebbs Spelling and grammar checking usually helps.  Having said this, what you're describing is kinda vague and not really easy to be able to track down what exactly's going on.  These games don't keep any kind of startup logs do they?

Comment: if I go into the Directory then there is a folder called "logs" if that's any help, I'm new to linux and I'm finding it really hard getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Launch as many of these programs as you can from a terminal.  You may at least see some error messages that way.  Don't think Blizzard has made a native Linux version, so you must be using WINE.  Can launch a Windows program from the terminal by changing to the directory where the program is installed and typing in something like "wine WoW.exe"

May be networking problems.  Are the correct ports open?  Does your computer have a different local IP address from before the upgrade, but your router is still forwarding the ports to the old address?

Answer (score 0):

These games are online so you definetely won't lose any progress reinstalling them :) . Try to install another copy of lol or wow in PlayOnLinux. Such problems always caused by changing video driver. My GTA San Andreas was broken because from 13.10 to 14.04 Nvidia driver version has changed (from 318 to 331). Reinstall of game helped me.